# PHP - How to extend SQLite3Result class

Tags: php, sqlite, extend

This is what I came up with so far:

```
class SQLite3_extended extends SQLite3 {
  public function query($string){
    $result = parent::query($string);
    if(is_bool($result))
      return $result;
    else
      return new SQLite3Result_extended($this);
  } 
}

class SQLite3Result_extended extends SQLite3Result {
  public function test(){
    echo 'SQLite3Result extended successfully!';
  } 
}
```

And I get this: Fatal error: Call to private SQLite3Result::__construct() from context 'SQLite3_extended

HOW do I extend SQLite3Result class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `SQLite3Result` class can only be instantiated internally by [`SQLite3::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php); there is no way to construct an instance of this class, or of a subclass, yourself.

If you want an extensible database class, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You can use a custom subclass for statements/results by calling [`PDO::setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) with the `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS` argument. As a bonus, it may enable you to support database engines other than SQLite.

Comment: If only I new the structure of SQLite3Result::__construct(), I could rewrite it in the extended database and set it as public. What can you say about that?

Comment: You can't. It's implemented in C as part of the sqlite3 extension.